# get value single value from array var that stores result of query php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-abstraction

I have a query that stores result of query like

```
$this->load->model('person/person_model');
$data['result'] = $this->person_model->get('tbl_person', array('id_person' => $some_key),TRUE);
```

this will return all the fields of person with `$some_key` (id,name,email...)
Then I need to pass $data but before I would like to use name and email of that result

so

```
$this->load->model('person/other_person_job_model');
$status= $this->other_person_job_model->get('tbl_other_person',array('name'=> ?  ),TRUE);
```

Then I could use `$status['name']` or  `$status['email']`
What should I put instead of **?** in the example above?
Should I use  `$data['result']['name']`  or something like that?
the get function is:

```
function get($table,$where=array(),$single=FALSE) {
        $q = $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
        $result = $q->result_array();
        if($single) {
            return $result[0];
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Not getting you. What should be put in means ? If you want to get record by name put name there or by email put email of user instead.

Comment: But How to get specific value, what would be the syntax if `$data['result']` is an array with all values, How to get name and email from it?

Comment: `var_dump($data['result'])` & check format of result. Might be  `$data['result']['name']`.

Comment: `$data['result']['name']` is not working, I get an error telling  Undefined offset

Comment: i am not getting exactly what you want...But i think u need to use $data[result]->name...
Or if it has more than one row use foreach loop to get your desire value

Comment: If `$data['result']` would be $data, to get email or name I will do `$data['email']` but that is not the case,....

Comment: use echo"<pre>";prin_r($data['result']); then show us the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use variable, like:

```
$this->load->model('person/person_model');
$result = $this->person_model->get('tbl_person', array('id_person' => $some_key),TRUE);
$data['name'] = $result->name;
$data['result'] = $result;
//and
$this->load->model('person/other_person_job_model');
$status= $this->other_person_job_model->get('tbl_other_person',array('name'=> $result->name  ),TRUE);
```

Comment: Is there a way to store result of query in your example like `$data['result'] ` ?

Comment: @cMinor result of query is stored in $result variable in my example code...and $data["result"] is assigned $result